Show message only in status bar in Oracle Forms 12c
Recently an Oracle Forms 6i based system has been migrated to Weblogic 12c and the 6i forms are presenting a peculiar problem: I have the problem that when I use the following line in a random trigger:
MESSAGE('Message text');
This message is displayed as a popup and in the bottom status bar, and what I want is that it is only displayed in the status bar, but not as a popup message.
I have tried putting the message only once, also twice MESSAGE (as in 6i), leaving a null MESSAGE after the message, but it still shows the message in a popup window.
I just want it to be displayed in the status bar. any suggestions?
I want is that it is only displayed in the status bar, but not as a popup message.

Maybe there's already some message that is occupying status bar, so Forms is kind of forced to display a pop-up window - otherwise your message would overwrite previous message.
Try to call clear_message first, and then message your own info.
